# Assign permanent variable in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

As the title says, I want to set a permanent variable in python, no matter if the program is restarted. I'm not talking about saving the variable in a document, instead of that, I mean doing like when you type "copyright" or "credits".

For example: in the command prompt of Windows, we have stuff like %USERNAME%. This is a permanent thing, but you can enter regedit and set a new permanent stuff like %PYTHON% and it will do whatever you write there.

Is this possible to do something similar in python?

Comment: Basically you want to create a predefined variable which will be always accessible through all Python scripts. Is it right?

Comment: Yes! that's what I want. Is that possible? @Qeek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create those kinds of variables and make it portable. You should probably create a simple package e.g. `myvars`. The content should looks like this:

```
MY_VAR = 10
```

then from your script (or from interactive console) you'll call

```
from myvars import MY_VAR
```

from that point you have accessible variable called `MY_VAR`. If you write new value into the variable it will be applied only on the running Python instance in other words it won't be saved in the file.

If you want to change the variable later you just edit the `myvars` package.

For more information about packages you can look at the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Oh, so isn't possible to create default variables like "credits" or "copyright". I thought it was possible. :( thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in order to store the value of a variable permanently, you should either save it to a file or to a database. The first option would be the easiest one as you can simply create a .txt file within your directory and save the variable value. This can be updated, deleted, read anytime you want.